# Excel PrintPreview

Tags: c#, .net, excel

The Following is my code to print preview for an excel document.

The compilation is successful.

But the preview window is not visible. Can any body point me what is the error. Is there is need to add any more codings or dlls.

(Note: The Document contains data)

```
        Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();

        Excel.Workbook wb = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\\Documents and Settings\\Admin\\Desktop\\DoCoMo\\news5.xls",
                        Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                        Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                        Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
        Excel.Worksheet ws = (Excel.Worksheet)wb.Worksheets[1];
        bool userDidntCancel = excelApp.Dialogs[Excel.XlBuiltInDialog.xlDialogPrintPreview].Show(                
                                    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                                    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                                    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                                    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                                    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                                    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);




        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        wb.Close(false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
        excelApp.Quit();
```

Answer (score 4):

You might have to manually show the Excel window:

```
excelApp.Visible = true;
```

However, I've heard that they are some issues related to specific Excel versions (it might work for some, and not for others).

Comment: +1 for a warning on version issues.  I know this is over a year old, but any specific info on who it "might work for" and who it might not work for?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the *Visible* property of the *excelApp* to true.

```
Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();
excelApp.Visible = true;
```